# How to update a javascript bundle file from a typescript file being saved?

Tags: typescript, web-essentials

I have a **Visual Studio** project with **Web Essentials** and **Typescript** and **javascript** bundling.

I would like to be able to do the following:

1. change a typescript file (abc.ts) and save it (ok)
2. the changes are compiled into javascript file abc.js (ok)
3. after the abc.js file is updated see the javascript bundle file BundlePage.js.bundle updated - this doesn't work !

Basically, whenever I change a typescript file and after saving it I would like to see the corresponding javascript change reflected in the javascript bundle file.

Currently, in order to do this now I have some manual options:

- a) open the bundle xml file BundlePage.js.bundle and save it as it will update the whole bundle file BundlePage.js
- b) do Alt+Shift+I to update all bundle files in the project; very clumsy as it updates all bundle files in the project and checks them out
- c) or edit and save the typescript's javascript file (abc.js) which after the save triggers the update of the bundled javascript file BundlePage.js.

Does anyone have any idea of how to make any change in a typescript file to trigger the update of the affected javascript bundle files ?

Here's my software:

- windows 7
- MS Visual Studio Premium 2012 Version 11.0.60315.01 Update 2
- MS .NET Framework Version 4.5.50709
- Web Essentials 2.6
- Typescript 0.8.3.

Thanks in advance for your help.
Miguel.

Comment: Is it an ASP.NET WebForms project or ASP MVC project? With ASP MVC at least, you can use the built-in "bundling and minification" feature to do this for you automatically.

Answer (score 2):

It should work. The bug was fixed in version 1.8 http://webessentials.uservoice.com/forums/140520-general/suggestions/3358548-update-bundle-on-save-on-an-included-file-suppor quote "Both JS and CSS bundles are updated whenever the .bundle file or any .js/.css file included in the bundle is updated". Works on my machine as well.

Answer (score 0):

Web Essentials Bundling is apparently not supported in VS2012, the first supported version is 2013: http://vswebessentials.com/features/bundling# (and click on 2012 filter)

Comment: @hiro-protagonist, It is not a link only answer.  The link is for reference.  It so happens the answer is short.

Comment: agreed & retracted. sorry.